# A formula which is true in all possibilities for variables in IPL

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, modal-logic

Let $\mathcal{F}(n, 2^m)$ be an intuitionistic Kripke in Fig. 1, which is formed by the set
$$
\left\{(i, j)\in \omega \times \omega \mid (0 \leq i \leq n-3, 0 \leq j \leq 1) \vee (i= n-2, 0 \leq j \leq 2^{m}-1) \vee (i=n-1, j=0)\right\}
$$

and its ordering:
$$
\left (i, j) \leq (i', j') \leftrightarrow (i, j) = (i', j') \vee i > i' \right.
$$
[image]

Assuming $\phi(p_1, ..., p_m)$ is a formula with $m$ variables and $\mathcal{F}(n, 2^m) \nvDash \phi$. $V$ is a valuation on $\mathcal{F}(n, 2^m)$ and for any $(n-2, x)$ and $(n-2, y)$, there is a variable $p_t$, such that $(n-2, x) \in V(p_t)$ iff $(n-2, y) \notin V(p_t)$. Thus $\{(n-2, j) \mid 0 \leq j \leq 2^{m}-1 \}$ are exactly all $2^m$ possibilities for $p_1, ..., p_m$. It is obvious that for every $(i, j)$ with $0 \leq i \leq n-3$, $(i, j) \models p_t$ and $(n-1, 0)\nvDash p_t$.

Is it possible that $(\mathcal{F}(n, 2^m), V) \models \phi$?

If $(\mathcal{F}(n, 2^m), V) \models \phi$, then every $(n-2, x)\models \phi$, but all (n-2, x) are exactly all $2^m$ possibilities for $p_1, ..., p_m$. Is it a contradiction to $\mathcal{F}(n, 2^m) \nvDash \phi$?

Comment: As you say, all variables are true under $V$ in all nodes $(i,j)$ with $i\le n-3$; thus, under $V$, you may as well collapse all the upper levels to a single point, i.e., $V$ makes true all formulas $\phi$ that are valid in all depth-$3$ frames with a single top node, i.e., all tautologies of $\mathsf{KC+BD_3}$. Since $\mathcal F(n,2^m)$ itself has neither a unique top node nor depth $3$, it’s trivial to find such $\phi$ that are not valid in $\mathcal F(n,2^m)$, e.g. $\neg p\lor\neg\neg p$ or the bounded depth axioms $\mathrm{bd}_k$ for $3\le k\le\min\{n-1,m\}$.

Comment: To be explicit, the $\mathrm{bd}_3$ axiom is $p_1\lor(p_1\to(p_2\lor(p_2\to(p_3\lor\neg p_3))))$.

Comment: Actually, already $\neg\neg p_i$ is true under any such $V$, but not valid in $\mathcal F(n,2^m)$ (or any other nonempty frame, for that matter).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, thank you for your help, you always help me a lot! If for any $V_i$
 in which $(i,0)$ and $(i,1)$ (fixed $i$) agree on every variable under $V_i$, we always have $(\mathcal{F}, V_i) \models \phi$, then is it a contradiction to $\mathcal{F} \nvDash \phi$.

Comment: It finally dawned on me where I’ve seen this frame before. It is called the Chinese lantern, and it is instrumental in Maksimova, Skvortsov, and Shehtman’s proofs that Medvedev’s logic and its modal companions are not finitely axiomatizable https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dan&paperid=42643&option_lang=eng , https://www.jstor.org/stable/20015517 .

Comment: You must be right. I learn it from ZALÁN GYENIS's paper STANDARD BAYES LOGIC IS NOT FINITELY AXIOMATIZABLE. I want to study these structures to prove further results about finitely axiomaztzable.